# Mailchimp re-use of trigger for subscribe new member

Tags: email, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

**Scenario:** New member is joining in list group 'A' [trigger detect this and sends mail] [workflow-A], then member according to condition leaves list group 'A' and is joined in to group 'B' [trigger detect this and sends mail] [workflow-B]. After some time, the member wants to be re-added in to the group 'A' [trigger does nothing].

**Questions:** Is resend same email  possible with using same workflow and trigger if condition is in both cases from Scenarios fullfiled. (If yes, how?)

Basically, can be triggered same email address 2 times (if the condition of trigger is fullfiled in both cases)?

**I tried few operations below:**

**Remove subscribers from workflow => it does not work**

**Remove subscribers from list and re-adding => it does not work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is no. A subscriber can only be added to a workflow once.

This scenario sounds like it might be transactional in nature though and you may find more utility in a transactional mail service (like mandrill) as opposed to MailChimp which is really meant as a one to many service.